# VMIN=0 + select(), possible kernel bug?

Tags: linux, io, terminal, kernel

**Update:** [Simple Proof of Concept](https://gist.github.com/jmendeth/d55bfb52f8b5b5fe01e4) with explanation of different behaviours.

Suppose I use `tcgetattr` and `tcsetattr` to set `VMIN = 0, VTIME = 0` and remove `ICANON`, setting the terminal in raw mode.
A call to `read()` from stdin will never block. Am I right?

My question is: **should I expect `select()` on stdin to return immediately?**
From the man page:

> `select()` and `pselect()` allow a program to monitor multiple file descriptors, waiting until one or more of the file descriptors become "ready" for some class
>   of I/O operation (e.g., input possible).  A file descriptor is considered ready if **it is possible to perform the corresponding I/O operation** (e.g.,  read(2))
>   **without blocking**.

Based on that, my first answer would be «yes». However, in practice it *does* block on most Linux systems I've tested, but it does not block on some. **Is this a kernel bug?** **Is it recommended to use `VMIN = 0` and `select()` in that way?**

Comment: A short sample program which others can inspect (and consider whether your description is complete) would help get responses.

Comment: Sure! I'll add one. Somehow I didn't see your message before...

Comment: @ThomasDickey Done, see link.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be this: the array entries for `VMIN` and `VTIME` serve two purposes.  Referring to [POSIX termios](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/termios.h.html):

> the VMIN and VTIME subscripts may have the same values as the VEOF and VEOL subscripts, respectively.

The program reads the `attributes` value while in canonical mode, then changes it to non-canonical, and sets `VMIN` to zero.  But the [version shown](https://gist.github.com/jmendeth/d55bfb52f8b5b5fe01e4) does nothing with `VTIME` (that does not match the description in the question).

See for example *[Understanding UNIX termios VMIN and VTIME](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/termios-vmin-vtime.html)* (likewise, the Linux [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tcsetattr.3.html) for termios), where it notes that if both `VMIN` and `VTIME` are zero, then you can have a completely non-blocking read.

The termios manual page gives zero as the initial value for `VEOL`, while the [stty manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stty) page equates `<undef>` with `_POSIX_VDISABLE` (nonzero) (which agrees with [POSIX stty](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/stty.html)).  POSIX does not appear to specify an initial value for `eol`.

Normally `VEOL` would be `<undef>` as shown by `stty -a`.  Perhaps on the machines where you get a non-blocking read, this is not the case.  That need not be a *kernel* bug, but could be a configuration problem with the TTYs.

Comment: PoC now sets `VTIME = 0` as well. I've tested and I get the same different behaviours as before...

Comment: Note that if I remove the `select` call (leaving just a "blocking" `read`), the PoC behaves the same.

Comment: Clarification: Behaves the same across machines, the `read` always returns 0 immediately.

Comment: A non-blocking read is consistent with the documentation, because `VTIME` is now explicitly initialized.

Comment: Yes. Still, `select` behaviour is inconsistent across machines... On some it blocks until there's input, on others it returns immediately.